# Import compiled BB files to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, compilation, java-me

I`ve got a problem right now. 
I have an application in Blackberry reeady to install  (the alx file, the cod file, the csl file , the cso file, the debug files, the jad file, the jar file, the rapc file  ) but this app is for version 5 of Blackberry OS.

I had the idea to re-compile the files now ready for version 7 of Blackberry, but im having problems, first beacuse the jar file is inside full of .class files.

I'm a bit lost, help me please. All i  want to do is my app run under Blackberry OS version 7

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have an alx file wich I install in my blackberry version 5 and it is running OK, but when i install it in my version 7 Blackberry it runs but at the login screen when i press 'LOGIN' it keeps loading and never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS 5.0 application should run fine on OS 7.0, just install the cod as you would for an OS 5.0 device.  Applications on BB are forward compatible.

**Update**

I note the comment added.  It would be better to edit the question.  The idea is that you ask a detailed question, and in response, you get back a detailed answer.  So just use the Edit button to edit the question rather than adding a comment.

In addition, the focus on SO is on programming, rather than installing.  So this question, as currently written, doesn't really fit in here.

Moreover my answer still applies.  The cod file should work, without recompilation, on OS 7.0.  The error you describe does not sound to me like an error that would be resolved by recompiling on OS 7.0 (which you can't do anyway without the source files).  From your description it is likely that the problem is caused by some difference between the two BlackBerry devices, like the connection methods available or carrier used.  I am fairly confident the fact you are stuck on the Login is NOT related to OS 7.

My recommendation is that you go back to the people who developed the original program, and ask them to help you.

Comment: It is not working whats why I ask, i get the following error:

Comment: @user3539596 - can't see a following error....  Please update your question with that information.

Comment: Actually I dont get any error, it is just it doesnt login the external web service, can you help me checking my code?

Comment: Please update your problem description to explain completely what your issue is.

Comment: Ok,I did as a comment

Comment: Why do you want my email?  Are you prepared to pay for direct support?